# Most dominant color in RGB image - OpenCV / NumPy / Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I have a python image processing function, that uses tries to get the dominant color of an image. I make use of a function I found here https://github.com/tarikd/python-kmeans-dominant-colors/blob/master/utils.py

It works, but unfortunately I don't quite understand what it does and I learned that `np.histogram` is rather slow and I should use `cv2.calcHist` since it's 40x faster according to this: https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/db7/tutorial_py_histogram_begins.html

I'd like to understand how I have to update the code to use `cv2.calcHist`, or better, which values I have to input.

My function

```
def centroid_histogram(clt):
    # grab the number of different clusters and create a histogram
    # based on the number of pixels assigned to each cluster
    num_labels = np.arange(0, len(np.unique(clt.labels_)) + 1)
    (hist, _) = np.histogram(clt.labels_, bins=num_labels)

    # normalize the histogram, such that it sums to one
    hist = hist.astype("float")
    hist /= hist.sum()

    # return the histogram
    return hist
```

The `pprint` of `clt` is this, not sure if this helps

```
KMeans(algorithm='auto', copy_x=True, init='k-means++', max_iter=300,
    n_clusters=1, n_init=10, n_jobs=1, precompute_distances='auto',
    random_state=None, tol=0.0001, verbose=0)
```

My code can be found here: https://github.com/primus852/python-movie-barcode

I am a very beginner, so any help is highly appreciated.

As per request:

#### Sample Image

[image: Sample]

#### Most dominant color:

`rgb(22,28,37)`

#### Computation time for the Histogram:

`0.021515369415283203s`

Comment: Add a sample image, the computed dominant color and the time it takes to compute it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Two approaches using `np.unique` and `np.bincount` to get the most dominant color could be suggested. Also, in the linked page, it talks about `bincount` as a faster alternative, so that could be the way to go.

**Approach #1**

```
def unique_count_app(a):
    colors, count = np.unique(a.reshape(-1,a.shape[-1]), axis=0, return_counts=True)
    return colors[count.argmax()]
```

**Approach #2**

```
def bincount_app(a):
    a2D = a.reshape(-1,a.shape[-1])
    col_range = (256, 256, 256) # generically : a2D.max(0)+1
    a1D = np.ravel_multi_index(a2D.T, col_range)
    return np.unravel_index(np.bincount(a1D).argmax(), col_range)
```

Verification and timings on `1000 x 1000` color image in a dense range `[0,9)` for reproducible results -

```
In [28]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000,1000,3))
    ...: 
    ...: print unique_count_app(a)
    ...: print bincount_app(a)
[4 7 2]
(4, 7, 2)

In [29]: %timeit unique_count_app(a)
1 loop, best of 3: 820 ms per loop

In [30]: %timeit bincount_app(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.7 ms per loop
```

**Further boost**

Further boost upon leveraging [`multi-core` with `numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/blob/master/doc/user_guide.rst#enabling-intel-vml-support) for large data -

```
import numexpr as ne

def bincount_numexpr_app(a):
    a2D = a.reshape(-1,a.shape[-1])
    col_range = (256, 256, 256) # generically : a2D.max(0)+1
    eval_params = {'a0':a2D[:,0],'a1':a2D[:,1],'a2':a2D[:,2],
                   's0':col_range[0],'s1':col_range[1]}
    a1D = ne.evaluate('a0*s0*s1+a1*s0+a2',eval_params)
    return np.unravel_index(np.bincount(a1D).argmax(), col_range)
```

Timings -

```
In [90]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000,1000,3))

In [91]: %timeit unique_count_app(a)
    ...: %timeit bincount_app(a)
    ...: %timeit bincount_numexpr_app(a)
1 loop, best of 3: 843 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 12 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 8.94 ms per loop
```

Comment: That's so great and it's really fast. However, I cannot get the color from `.bincount_app` when I do `color = utils.bincount_app(image).astype('uint8').tolist()` it says `'tuple' object has no attribute 'astype'`. Same thing with `unique_count` works like a charm, but seems to be slower.

Comment: @PrimuS Simply do : `list(bincount_numexpr_app(a))`.

Comment: Hm, sorry I feel useless, but 
`color = list(utils.bincount_numexpr_app(image))` and `cv2.rectangle(barcode, (0, 0), (width, height), color, -1)` leads to `Scalar value for argument 'color' is not numeric`

Comment: @PrimuS I am not sure about the expected input to color argument there. Mayb it expects a tuple. So, try : `color = utils.bincount_numexpr_app(image)` or even `color = tuple(utils.bincount_numexpr_app(image))`?

Comment: @PrimuS Is `barcode` a grayscale image or a color one?

Comment: Barcode Rect is this `barcode = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype="uint8")` and from the OpenCV docs, it expects `CvScalar color`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173302/discussion-between-divakar-and-primus).

Answer (score 13):

@Divakar has given a great answer. But if you want to port your own code to OpenCV, then:

```
    img = cv2.imread('image.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

    data = np.reshape(img, (-1,3))
    print(data.shape)
    data = np.float32(data)

    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
    flags = cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS
    compactness,labels,centers = cv2.kmeans(data,1,None,criteria,10,flags)

    print('Dominant color is: bgr({})'.format(centers[0].astype(np.int32)))
```

Result for your image:

> Dominant color is: bgr([41 31 23])

Time it took: 0.10798478126525879 secs

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent code for `cv2.calcHist()` is to replace:

```
(hist, _) = np.histogram(clt.labels_, bins=num_labels)
```

with

```
dmin, dmax, _, _ = cv2.minMaxLoc(clt.labels_)

if np.issubdtype(data.dtype, 'float'): dmax += np.finfo(data.dtype).eps
else: dmax += 1

hist = cv2.calcHist([clt.labels_], [0], None, [num_labels], [dmin, dmax]).flatten()
```

Note that [`cv2.calcHist`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d6/dc7/group__imgproc__hist.html#ga4b2b5fd75503ff9e6844cc4dcdaed35d) only accepts `uint8` and `float32` as element type.

### Update

It seems like opencv's and numpy's binning differs from each other as the histograms differ if the number of bins doesn't map the value range:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2

#data = np.random.normal(128, 1, (100, 100)).astype('float32')
data = np.random.randint(0, 256, (100, 100), 'uint8')
BINS = 20

np_hist, _ = np.histogram(data, bins=BINS)

dmin, dmax, _, _ = cv2.minMaxLoc(data)
if np.issubdtype(data.dtype, 'float'): dmax += np.finfo(data.dtype).eps
else: dmax += 1

cv_hist = cv2.calcHist([data], [0], None, [BINS], [dmin, dmax]).flatten()

plt.plot(np_hist, '-', label='numpy')
plt.plot(cv_hist, '-', label='opencv')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(15, 7)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved version of @Divakar's answer. Separate solution for RGBA image. Fully transparent pixels will not be counted for the RGBA image.

```py
import numpy as np


def most_common_color_RGB(image: np.ndarray):
    """input image ndarray shape should be RGB shape, for example: (512, 512, 3)"""
    a2D = image.reshape(-1, image.shape[-1])

    col_range = (256, 256, 256)  # generically : a2D.max(0)+1
    a1D = np.ravel_multi_index(a2D.T, col_range)
    return np.unravel_index(np.bincount(a1D).argmax(), col_range)


def most_common_color_RGBA(image_RGBA: np.ndarray):
    """input image ndarray shape should be RGBA shape, for example: (512, 512, 4)"""
    RGB_pixels = image_RGBA.reshape(-1, 4)
    # remove transparent pixels
    just_non_alpha = RGB_pixels[RGB_pixels[:, 3] != 0]
    if just_non_alpha.shape[0] == 0:
        return False
    # delete alpha channel
    just_non_alpha = np.delete(just_non_alpha, 3, axis=1)
    col_range = (256, 256, 256)  # generically : a2D.max(0)+1
    a1D = np.ravel_multi_index(just_non_alpha.T, col_range)
    return np.unravel_index(np.bincount(a1D).argmax(), col_range)
```

Answer (score 0):

Awesome answer from @Divakar

With bit shifting instead of multiplication, it might be even a little faster. It seems to have a bigger effect on large pictures with more colors

```
import numexpr as ne
def get_dom_color(x):
    def get_color_back(code):
        blue = int(code % 256)
        green = int((code % (256 * 256) - blue) / 256)
        red = int((code - blue - green * 256) / (256 * 256))
        return red, green, blue
    arr = x.reshape(-1,x.shape[-1])
    outa=ne.evaluate('(c1 << 16) + (c2 << 8) + c3',global_dict={},local_dict={'c1':arr[...,0],'c2':arr[...,1],'c3':arr[...,2]})
    return get_color_back(np.bincount(outa).argmax())
def bincount_numexpr_app(a):
    a2D = a.reshape(-1,a.shape[-1])
    col_range = (256, 256, 256) # generically : a2D.max(0)+1
    eval_params = {'a0':a2D[:,0],'a1':a2D[:,1],'a2':a2D[:,2],
                   's0':col_range[0],'s1':col_range[1]}
    a1D = ne.evaluate('a0*s0*s1+a1*s0+a2',eval_params)
    return np.unravel_index(np.bincount(a1D).argmax(), col_range)
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randint(0,255,(4000,4000,3))
%timeit bincount_numexpr_app(x)
%timeit get_dom_color(x)
427 ms ± 14.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
412 ms ± 7.91 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```