# Activate/deactivate pixel based on predominant color

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, mask, roi

I'm doing a real time image processing at about 20 FPS.
I'm trying to filter 3 colors (using opencv, python). Those are: **red**, **blue** and **yellow** from a frame in which the light is not always constant (meaning sometimes the ambiental light can make my red pixel (B=119, G=84, R=199), and sometimes (R=60, G=0, B=0) - *this is when the light comes right in front of the camera*).

I know about a formula like so : if `2R-B-G` *is grater or equal to 0*, then the pixel will go high (it remains unchanged). If the pixel *goes negative*, i should make it black. The problem is that this involves a pixel by pixel processing and i'm not sure it is what i'm searching for. I would like to try this approach but i don't know how could i do it a little bit faster (masking  and `cv2.bitwise_and()` after each pixel checked is the only ideea that I have, and it will take ages)

For the moment, i am just creating a *binary_mask*

```
cv2.inRange(bgr_sliced_img, (low_blue, low_green, low_red), (upper_blue, upper_green, upper_red))
```

The problem with this is that it is impossible to adjust the parameters so that i get the red /blue/ yellow values visible in darker images as well as in bright images *without seeing other wrong objects*.

[I've read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50899692/most-dominant-color-in-rgb-image-opencv-numpy-python) and i don't really know how could i use the median intensity in my frame. I think this is close to what i want, but i have no ideea how could i implement this.

I will provide 3 pictures that ilustrates the problem . The traffic stop sign is red, but because of ambiental light, its red is changed.

I would like to find some algorithm that will "see" the red color in each 3 pictures without the need of manual modifying parameters.

*I should mention that i'm searching for the traffic sign in a region of interest of about 100x100 pixels, not in the entire image

[image: STOP_C]

[image: STOP_B]

[image: STOP_A]

Comment: you can use HSV color code for easy filtering

Comment: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html

Comment: it is still not good enough the HSV. I have also tried the HSL. I would like something to check in the image and see if the majority of the pixels are darker, search for darker red...

Comment: How could I improve the method of analyzing each pixel and checking if blue is predominant color ? Does it exists another method that makes it quickly?

Comment: Can you append your question with the code and resulting images from trying HSV and it not working?