# How to detect object color efficiently?

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, classification

I'm trying to detect a object's color in an efficient way. Let's assume I run a YOLO model and crop the object region given the bounding boxes. Given the cropped object image, then what's the most efficient and accurate way to detect the color of the object?

Previously, I trained a YOLO model to detect the color (10 class of colors), but running 2 deep learning models is too slow for my real-time requirements. I need the color detection/classification part to be very fast, preferably not using deep learning. Maybe pure Python or OpenCV or whatnot.

I wrote this piece of code that resizes the image to a 1x1 pixel. I then visualize the color in a square. But it's not accurate at all. Just too off.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def get_dominant_color(pil_img):
    img = pil_img.copy()
    img = img.convert("RGBA")
    img = img.resize((1, 1), resample=0)
    dominant_color = img.getpixel((0, 0))
    return dominant_color

# Specify the path to your image
image_path = "path/to/your/image.jpg"

# Open the image using PIL
image = Image.open(image_path)

# Get the dominant color
dominant_color = get_dominant_color(image)

# Print the color in RGB format
print("Dominant Color (RGB):", dominant_color[:3])

# Create a new image with a 100x100 square of the dominant color
square_size = 100
square_image = Image.new("RGB", (square_size, square_size), dominant_color[:3])

# Display the square image
square_image.show()
```

Comment: Generally speaking this is a hard problem -- does the color of the windshield count as the color of the car? The tires? The logo? I'd assume no, but unfortunately, you have no way of knowing what portion of a vehicle will be captured in advance. This problem would get a little easier with one of Yolo's segmentation models to avoid some noise, but this thread may be helpful if you're looking for the dominant color in a crop of each bounding box:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50899692/most-dominant-color-in-rgb-image-opencv-numpy-python

Comment: Here another thread on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241929/python-find-dominant-most-common-color-in-an-image#3244061

Comment: Quantize the image and get the median intensity value.

Comment: @A10 yeah true of course. Just like human intuition, the body of car should define car color. But I understand without deep learning it will be a difficult problem. We should use some tricks or maybe use pixel colors or histogram etc.

Comment: @Claudio resize to 1 pixel haha. Have to try that. But still have to define the color of the single pixel.

Comment: @stateMachine hmm interesting. Can you write your solution?

Comment: What he's saying is essentially to create a histogram, just as you suggested.  That's likely to be a good path here.

Comment: I tried the "resize image down to 1 pixel" solution. No it's not working. Very off.

Comment: May you provide the list of colors you want to detect in the images and the description of what you consider to be a color similar to the color in the list, so that I can provide you with an answer?

Comment: 12: Red, white, black, silver, gray, yellow, orange, blue, pink, brown, beige, green. Just use your human intuition of color. Don't worry

Comment: @TinaJ :please consider to revert your question to having the images in it and the entire context again. Without the context of the images and the in the question stated goal of fast determination of colors of cars detected in a video frames my answer does not make sense anymore ...

Comment: @TinaJ : the current text of your question is not the question I have written an answer to. If the objects in the images contain objects like triangles or circles filled with a solid color it changes entirely the question invalidating my answer, Generally please refrain from changing vital details of your question after you have got an answer, because this invalidates the answer and makes it obsolete (even if accepted).

Comment: Yeah i know. It is still applicable. I'll slightly change my question again. I thought maybe those images shouldn't get public

Comment: if the images should be removed, please flag your own Question for moderator intervention as the images are available in the history! otherwise, I think this should be rolled back to keep the original context (also to my knowledge all posted content is CC-BY-SA 4.0 see https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public **Subscriber Content**) .. it's definitely not _vandalism_, but imo making the Question more generic makes it worse - while it may duplcate a general topic, being specific to a topic feels more discoverable and useful to the community!

Comment: @TinaJ :  I think that providing images is a fair use, but ... ok ... you may make the registration plates unreadable - this should be enough to make them suitable for public viewing. I will provide the adapted images short in my answer, so you can take them (the registration plates are smudged out).

Comment: @TinaJ : I think it is worth the effort as your question attracted many visitors interested in knowing about car color detection from images who can profit from both, your question and my answer,

Comment: No please remove the images or at least just keep one. They are private images and shouldn't get public

Comment: @TinaJ :thanks for editing my answer - nice car there now by the way :) . What is the reason of not reverting your question to the question about car colors? Do you expect some further comments on to any object generalized question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me provide a summary of all the following voluminous content of my answer in one single sentence:

**There is no coding solution to expectations based on wrong assumptions.**

In other words your question *"How to detect car color efficiently?"* is based on a not true assumption that it is possible to detect car color without further segmentation of the image and a deep analysis of entire areas of the single extracted segments along with the relationships between these areas.

If you want try to get a coding solution anyway, I suggest an "upside down" approach to what you want to achieve consisting of following steps:

- define the exact rgb() values of all car colors you want to detect in the images. For example, as you suggested in a comment, the rgb() values of 12 colors: red, white, black, silver, gray, yellow, orange, blue, pink, brown, beige and green.
- define a function which can be used to decide if a color is similar to a given one
- make sure that in the list of colors you use there isn't a pair of colors which are considered similar when using the color similarity function. In case of the mentioned set make for example the pairs (gray,silver), (white,beige), (beige,yellow) clearly distinguishable.
- decide about the threshold of the pixel amount in the image which need to be similar to a given color from the list in order to consider it as the car color
- adjust the overall brightness of the image to a pre-defined level in order to make the color similarity function return better results. Consider to take the entire image and not only the bounding box with the detected car in it to decide about the brightness adjustment.
- run once through the pixels of sized down image and collect the amounts of pixels similar to colors in the list up to the point where the amount exceeds the threshold of being the color of the car
- tune the factor for scaling down, brightness adjustment, the rgb() values in the list of colors, the color similarity function and the threshold of the amount of pixels with similar colors in order to arrive at a solution satisfying both your intuitive color perception and the image processing speed.

As you arrive at tuning you will probably notice why *A10* in the comment to your question speaks about a hard problem. Is a white car not a gray car at very cloudy weather short before the sun goes down?

To cover your color intuition you gain from analysis of all the image details and image content (you see in the image if the sun shines or if it is cloudy or dark and adjust your color criteria intuitively to this like taking for example thrown shadows and car window areas out of consideration) you will need much more than a fast and simple color comparison. In other words, you will probably realize that there is no way around training a learning model on gigabytes of images and no way around using faster hardware to achieve higher processing speed.

In order to dive a bit behind the reasons for your unrealistic expectations I suggest you read about the silver color for example at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_(color)) . Here an excerpt:

> > The visual sensation usually associated with the metal silver is its metallic shine. This cannot be reproduced by a simple solid color because the shiny effect is due to the material's brightness varying with the surface angle to the light source.

from which you can see, that it is impossible to identify a silver car color, because silver is not an R,G,B color of an image pixel, but the result of the overall impression of the entire color surface under the lighting conditions perceived from the context of all the details in the image.

Notice that considering the above revelation the actual purpose of the suggested step of:

> > - define the exact rgb() values of all car colors you want to detect in the images. For example, as you suggested in a comment, the rgb() values of 12 colors: red, white, black, silver, gray, yellow, orange, blue, pink, brown, beige and green.

is to make you aware of the limitations of the proposed approach and the fact that you won't be able to define silver, white and gray colors in a way which will go along with the with the human eye perceived car color.

By the way: it could be helpful to arrive at better results compared to the code you posted in your question cropping the images to get rid of the frames indicating the cars and then split the images into two halves, an upper and a lower one, and then decide about the result comparing the result for both of the images. Splitting to upper and lower parts can help to eliminate the impact of large dark car windows and detect inconsistencies in the color detection. Best would be to have a detection able to provide precise contour not only the rectangle - this would eliminate the noise because of the road surface and else surrounding. Depending on results from evaluating a huge amount of images you may decide to divide the images in vertical direction in three parts, not only two to improve the results.
Notice also that effectivity of dividing the image into strips depends on the camera perspective, so for the white and yellow car simple vertical splitting will be sufficient, but in case of the silver and red car vertical splitting along with cropping a parallelogram will give better results. In other words the camera perspective should be a parameter evaluated by the method obtaining the car color.

[image]

Comment: Good tips. But Im actually looking for a code solution.

Comment: You have got code solutions already if you follow the links to code solutions given in the comments to your question ... but you seem to be not satisfied with the results ... so you need to code your own one.

Comment: @TinaJ it seems unreasonable to expect a code solution without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to extend

Comment: Ok just updated the post with my trials.

Comment: To build on the comment regarding lighting conditions, you may find that you have better luck by converting to the HSV color space instead of working in RGB: [HSV thread](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2687/why-do-we-use-the-hsv-colour-space-so-often-in-vision-and-image-processing). This is still going to be a hard problem regardless, but a good choice of color space can minimize some of the difficulty.

Comment: @A10 : the color space does not matter in determining the color palette of car color classification. What does matter is how you compare or group colors in the color evaluating part of code. Depending on specific needs there are other color schemes next to HSV worth to be considered in this context. I am using for example LAB for determination of color similarity Anyway, color scheme does not solve the problem of different human color perception depending on surrounding colors in the image,

Comment: @Claudio, absolutely, the choice of color space doesn't _really_ matter, and in principle, any color space will do. However, with HSV, color thresh holding for segmentation based on color is easier . [For example, by separating a sunflower based on "yellow"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47483966/9453914). RGB, LAB, HSV, the choice is rather arbitrary and dependent on application -- different color spaces can make certain applications a little easier to deal with. Segmentation can also be done fairly easily in LAB, especially when compared to RGB.